# Icon works fine, expect on launcher itself

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to build an app, but the main problem i'm having is that my icon isn't displaying like it should. When I install the app, the icon is the right one. but on my launcher screen its the default Phonegap one. Does anyone know how this could be possible?

these are my configs;

Phonegap config.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="12" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
</widget>
```

Cordova config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <access origin="*" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
</widget>
```

Android Manifext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.phonegap.helloworld.androidsplashscreentimer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher">       
        <!-- Main activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.phonegap.helloworld.HelloWorld"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've replaced all the default phonegap icons and splashscreens with my own..

Comment: where are you checking the code? In device or emulator?

Comment: Device, Xiaomi M2S running MIUI V5

Answer (score 0):

On the left side you see res/drawable/ic_launcher.jpg. Add your ic_launcher.png or whatever, and it's done.

In Android Manifest:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

change them.

Comment: to android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:logo="@drawable/icon"?

Comment: add me on skype: clockdealer then i can show it to you better im bad in english :D